# Automatic Apache Alias definitions

Tags: apache-2.2, alias

I have a folder full of sites: `/var/www`

I have a domain: `example.com`

I want to write a rule in my `httpd.conf` that will setup an alias for each site in `/var/www`.

For example: `/var/www/hello/public` can be accessed via `example.com/hello`.

At the moment I am just writing my alias definitions manually, for each site: `Alias /hello "/var/www/hello/public/"`

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make `/var/www` your `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: Because the routing is to the `public` folder, not the `root` - `/hello` = `/var/www/hello/public`.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I missed that.  In that case, Gabor's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest solution would be to use [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) instead.  It does not do *exactly* what you described, but it's very close.

1. Enable `vhost_alias_module` using whatever technique your distribution prefers (`a2enmod vhost_alias` on Debian-based distros).
2. Add these directives to `httpd.conf`:

   ```
   UseCanonicalName Off
   VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1/public
   ```
3. Create a wildcard DNS entry for example.com so any subdomain of example.com is directed to your server.

Now accessing "hello.example.com" will load the site located in `/var/www/hello/public`.

Alternatively, as mentioned by Gabor, you can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).  The solution I'm going to outline assumes that you have no other content under example.com.

1. Enable [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) using whatever mechanism your distro prefers (`a2enmod rewrite` on Debian-based distros).
2. Add these directives to the `VirtualHost` for example.com:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(.*) /var/www/$1/public/$2
   ```

This will rewrite a request for "example.com/hello/steve" to `/var/www/hello/public/steve`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a vhost for your domain and webroot. Write a rewrite rule instead of aliasing.

Comment: What would the `RewriteRule` look like in this case?

Comment: Well, a rewrite map can work here, but it's likely not quite as performant as the other solution.

Comment: It would be useful to at least outline what the rewrite rule would look like.

Comment: I've outlined one below.